# Two columns into One

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to combine two columns into one where one column has null values.  It looks like this:

```
| Order Number | MOP    | MOP2   |
| 12345        | Cash   |        |
| 12346        | Credit |        |
| 12347        | Visa   | Cash   |
| 12348        | Credit |        |
```

The Query I am running looks like this:

```
Select  
  ORDER.OrderHistory.OrderNo  
  ,ORDER.OrderHistory.MOP 
  ,ORDER.OrderHistory.MOP2 
From  
  ORDER.OrderHistory
```

I am attempting to get it to look like this:

```
| Order Number | MOP    | 
| 12345        | Cash   |  
| 12346        | Credit |
| 12347        | Visa   | 
| 12347        | Cash   |
| 12348        | Credit |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `union` the two columns into the same column in your dataset:

```sql
-- This query will return all your data rows
select o.OrderNo
      ,o.MOP
from ORDER.OrderHistory as o

union all

-- And then this one will get all where the MOP2 column is not null
select o.OrderNo  
      ,o.MOP2 
from ORDER.OrderHistory as o
where o.MOP2 is not null
```